# Plot 3D figure in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

[image]Consider I have a 1D array X = ([1, 2, 3]), and for each element in X,  we have a corresponding 2D plot.

For example, we have a function z=f(y, X), and X is a parameter in this function, when we take a different value from X, we have a different 2D plot.

So what I want to do is to plot this in one figure, it is kind of a 3D plot, we have three axises, one is X, one is y and one is z=f(y, X), so how to plot this figure?

Thank you.
PS:I have uploaded a picture. What I want to plot is this kind of figure.

Comment: There are various ways to visualize a 'stack' of 2D plots. How would you like the 2D plots to be arranged exactly? Can you give an example of how they look like? Wouldn't simply plotting them as subplots work just as well?

Comment: @Rodin. Thanks for replying.  I want all these 2D plots are displayed in the same figure so that I can draw some conclusions from them more easily.What I wish to see is an array of 2D plot placed along one direction(In my example, along x direction) and separated by a distance(In my example, the distance is 1 along x direction)  Could you tell me one way to visualize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a grid of subplots should help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)-5
Ys = np.array([x**i for i in range(5)])
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 2))
for i, y in enumerate(Ys):
    plt.subplot(1, len(Ys), i+1)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('x^%d' % i)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I use `plt.tight_layout()` in the example, but you might want to consider removing it and playing with `plt.subplots_adjust` instead. The x-labels (x^0, x^1, etc.) are in my example placed by giving each subplot a title, but you might want to consider using `plt.figtext()` to manually place them in the exact location you want. Finally, check http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html for some more cool subplot arrangements.

Comment: Thanks Robin. However, what I want to achieve is that all these plot are in the same figure,  kind of like a 3D plotting. Not in the form of subplot.

Comment: By 'in the same figure', do you mean in the same axes? Perhaps you could make a sketch of what it is you're looking for exactly, otherwise I have to keep guessing.

Comment: @Robin. I already uploaded a picture in my question. You may check it.